# jquery.validate suppresses click/touch events, stopping iscroll4 from working

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-mobile, mobile, iscroll4

I'm building a JQM app, it's running inside cordova/phonegap on android at the moment.

I have a simple page with a form, inside an iscroll wrapper for scrolling.
This works fine, until I use jquery.validate plugin on the form.

It seems that the jquery.validate plugin is taking over the click/touch events and not letting them get up to iscroll.

If I click/touch in an area outside of the form, I can scroll normally, but if I click anywhere inside the form, nada.

I'm using JQM 1.3.2, JQuery 1.9.1 and jquery.validate 1.11.1

Any ideas? So frustrating...

Comment: Success... After much screwing around, I have discovered it was jquery.touchToClick, a jquery plugin to remove the 200ms delay waiting for double tap.

Answer (score 0):

Success...

After much screwing around, I have discovered it was jquery.touchToClick, a jquery plugin to remove the 200ms delay waiting for double tap.

Including this plugin seems to have had the effect of everything working everywhere else, except with iscroll and jquery.validate for some reason!